# How add display: block when anchor tag class is active with jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In my case I have menu like this:

```
<li class="">
   <a href="#" class="">Accounts</i></a>
   <ul style="display: none;">
      <li class=""><a href="https://example.test/profile/index" class="active ">Profile</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="https://example.test/profile/edit" class="">Edit </a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

How to add style display block if anchor tag is active?

Comment: `"add style display block"` to which element(s)?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius to ul

Comment: How is the hyperlink to have the `active` class applied if the parent (`UL`) is hidden?

Comment: what do you mean by active ?

Comment: So how ? to add style block to ul if anchor tag active

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove the "i" element closing tag from your "Accounts" link. After that You should not use inline styling when you are changing display value, instead use separate css file. I would move the display : none from inline to separate css file using selector.

```css
ul {
  display: none;
}
// use this if you want to hover
a:hover + ul {
  display: block;
}
// use this if you want to click
a:focus + ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Its doesnt work for me, add style block if anchor is active however if user reload the page too

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly simple to modify the display property of the parent element based upon some property of a child element using Javascript but in this case I'm not sure how the hyperlink will be assigned the `active` class when it resides within a hidden element (`ul`)...

```js
const getparent=(n,e)=>{//utility to find ancestor node of particular type
  while( n!=document.querySelector(e) )n=n.parentNode;
  return n;
}

// find all nodes that match the `active` class criteria and navigate up the DOM
// until the UL element is found - change it's display property
document.querySelectorAll('li a.active').forEach( a => getparent(a,'ul').style.display='block' )
```

```html
<li class="">
   <a href="#" class=""><i>Accounts</i></a>
   <ul style="display: none;">
      <li class=""><a href="https://example.test/profile/index" class="active ">Profile</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="https://example.test/profile/edit" class="">Edit </a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: I got error Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "parentNode", n is null

Comment: Where and how are you applying the above code? The snippet works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

For Menu Try this will helpfull

```
.menu ul{
position: absolute;
display: none;
}
.menu >li{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
position: relative;

}
.menu li a{
display: block;
padding: 0px 10px;
}
.menu li:hover ul{
display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down3</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down3</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```